# What do ref, val and out mean on method parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm looking for a clear, concise and accurate answer.

Ideally as the actual answer, although links to good explanations welcome.

This also applies to VB.Net, but the keywords are different - `ByRef` and `ByVal`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By default (in C#), passing an object to a function actually passes a copy of the reference to that object. Changing the parameter itself only changes the value in the parameter, and not the variable that was specified.

```
void Test1(string param)
{
    param = "new value";
}

string s1 = "initial value";
Test1(s1);
// s1 == "initial value"
```

Using `out` or `ref` passes a reference to the variable specified in the call to the function. Any changes to the value of an `out` or `ref` parameter will be passed back to the caller.

Both `out` and `ref` behave identically except for one slight difference: `ref` parameters are required to be initialised before calling, while `out` parameters can be uninitialised. By extension, `ref` parameters are guaranteed to be initialised at the start of the method, while `out` parameters are treated as uninitialised.

```
void Test2(ref string param)
{
    param = "new value";
}

void Test3(out string param)
{
    // Use of param here will not compile
    param = "another value";
}

string s2 = "initial value";
string s3;
Test2(ref s2);
// s2 == "new value"
// Test2(ref s3); // Passing ref s3 will not compile
Test3(out s2);
// s2 == "another value"
Test3(out s3);
// s3 == "another value"
```

**Edit**: As [dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060/what-do-ref-val-and-out-mean-on-method-parameters#13105) points out, the difference between `out` and `ref` is only enforced by the C# compiler, not by the CLR. As far as I know, VB has no equivalent for `out` and implements `ref` (as `ByRef`) only, matching the support of the CLR.

Comment: "copy of the reference to that object" or "reference to the copy of that object" ?

Answer (score 8):

One additional note about ref vs. out: The distinction between the two is enforced by the C# compiler. The CLR does not distinguish between between out and ref. This means that you cannot have two methods whose signatures differ only by an out or ref

```
void foo(int value) {}

// Only one of the following would be allowed

// valid to overload with ref
void foo(ref int value) {}

// OR with out
void foo(out int value) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

`out` means that the parameter will be initialised by the method:

```
int result; //not initialised

if( int.TryParse( "123", out result ) )
   //result is now 123
else
   //if TryParse failed result has still be 
   // initialised to its default value (0)
```

`ref` will force the underlying reference to be passed:

```
void ChangeMyClass1( MyClass input ) {
   input.MyProperty = "changed by 1";
   input = null;
   //can't see input anymore ... 
   // I've only nulled my local scope's reference
}

void ChangeMyClass2( ref MyClass input ) {
   input.MyProperty = "changed by 2";
   input = null;
   //the passed reference is now null too.
}

MyClass tester = new MyClass { MyProperty = "initial value" };

ChangeMyClass1( tester );
// now tester.MyProperty is "changed by 1"

ChangeMyClass2( ref tester );
// now tester is null
```

Answer (score 2):

One of my own questions at stackoverflow handles this topic too.
It handles about ["pass by reference" and "pass by value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027/pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) in different types of languages, [c# is included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027/pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value#2554) so maybe you can find some extra information there as well.

Basically it comes down to:

- ref: the parameter with the ref keyword will be passed *by reference*
- out: the parameter with the out keyword will be treated as an *output parameter*

but that's really the most basic answer you can give, as it is a little more complex than it is stated here