# Java ByteArrayOutputStream leaks in memory

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, javax.imageio, bytearrayoutputstream

I made a new question because this is different from my last thread. I now know what th e problem is more exact.

I create a new bytearrayoutputstream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

Nothing special.
Then, when I write an image to it, this way

```
ImageIO.write(image, "gif", byteArray);
```

the memory increases like 100 mb first, not in eclipse, but in "reality". Then it slowly increases after that each time I write a new image to that stream OR another!!

and after a while it stops working and kinda crashes.

I have tried closing it and all that, flushing, reseting, everything, but it still leaks memory. I want it to get away from memory when I stop using byteArray or null it.

```
System.gc();
```

wont help in this case.

Please help me and anything else you need to know I will answer and please return and reply back :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `System.gc()` manually in this case. If you've closed all the unused resources/streams/etc then you should be fine. Try increasing the limit on Java's memory

Comment: I agree. You're likely doing something wrong in code not shown.

Comment: You shouldnt be calling System.gc()...Java provides automatic gc function. Just dereference the variable. Also please include more code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java writing to ByteArrayOutputStream memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970742/java-writing-to-bytearrayoutputstream-memory-leak)

Answer (score 0):

Your usage pattern should be like:

```
while( keepRunning) {
     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();   
     ImageIO.write(image, "gif", byteArray);
}
```

If you do this faster than the JVM can collect garbage you'll eventually get a very long GC pause or an OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: nope. Not that quick. Maybe once a second I do that. But after that I close it.

Comment: Anyway I can use the same bytearrayoutputstream and reset it everytime I have used the data of it?

Comment: Are you resetting it now?  A reset won't get rid of any existing memory allocated, but it will overwrite the existing underlying byte[] buffer.

Comment: How can I get rid of it then?

Comment: You need to show a larger code snipped to really understand what you are doing. It should show where the ByteArrayOutputStream is initialized and where/when it is updated.

Comment: I have showed everything. Just call those 2 lines of code and the image should load in memory

Comment: In that case, you should try increasing your heap size and see if the JVM can GC before it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
 try{
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
  baos.flush();
  byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
  baos.close();
}catch(Exception ex){
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Does the same. Still ends up in memory

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing doesn't make any sense. You're taking an image out of memory and put it into memory again, this time as byte array.

You should put that image into a file or send over the network. Or, if you want just hold a copy, copy the image (not the byte array!) like I described here: [Bug in using Object.clone()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737182/bug-in-using-object-clone/12988354)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to a [similar answer I posted to another ByteArrayOutputStream question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13607298/203860).

There is no method in ByteArrayOutputStream that allows you to shrink the buffer. Reset changes the *position in the buffer*.

The solution for you is to

1. Use the constructor to specify the size of the buffer before use. When you are writing large objects to the stream, this will save a lot of memory and prevent OOM exceptions.
2. If you want to reuse your BAOS object, call reset. That will make the next write start at the beginning of the buffer.
3. The only way to free the memory is to remove all references to it. In the code above, you would say byteArray=null;