# Parameter Passing Techniques in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, parameter-passing

There are different parameter passing techniques like - Call By Value, Call By Reference, Call By Value Result, Call By Name, Call By Text and Call By Need in Programming Languages.

I have seen implementations of Call By Value and Call By Reference in C/C++; but the other techniques were taught only with simple plain examples, where we are given that this example uses say "Call By Value Result" and so answer accordingly. I was wondering whether the other techniques have ever been implemented in C/C++ or any other languages or were they just theoretical?

Comment: [... "C++ Does not support Pass-by-value-result, however it can be simulated."] [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5768802/2352671]

Comment: You should really stick to one language at a time.

Comment: Call by name explained here with some examples from ALGOL-60:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838079/what-is-pass-by-name-and-how-does-it-work-exactly

Answer (score 1):

C provided and still provides *pass by value* only.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it's only by value or by reference. The other techniques can be simulated using existing C++ language constructs - specially crafted conversion operators and constructors.

Comment: as an example the boost library [Parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

Check this the diff usage of parameters passing technique
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterPassing