# instance variable passing and modification in a function

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

How to pass an instance variable  as an argument to a function ?
Example:

```
@tmp = "blabla"
...
my_function(@tmp)
```

@tmp should be "hello"

```
def my_function(foo)
foo = "hello"
end
```

**Note**: I changed the wording of the title !

Comment: I don't understand your question..

Comment: I want to change the value of @tmp in my_function

Comment: Duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688391/why-doesnt-this-work-if-in-ruby-everything-is-an-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@temp` should not be "hello" the way you are doing it. If what you want to update `@tmp` I would change the way `my_function` works a bit:

```
def my_function
    'hello'
end

@tmp = "blabla"
...
@tmp = my_function
```

Ruby is a "pass by value" language. This might help explain it a bit better than I can: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/41160

Basically your `my_function` is only assigning `foo` "hello" while in the function, it then returns foo, but does not reassign the passed in object.

Comment: my_function could be more complicate. It was jusr an example.

Comment: @Bertaud so show the complete code. You can only Assign the instance to what the function returns.

Comment: @Bertaud, yes I understand that, but Ruby is still pass by value, meaning you will need to return the value and assign it to `@tmp` no matter how complicated `my_function` becomes.

Comment: shall i write: def my_function ... return value end and, after  @tmp = my_function(@tmp)

Comment: You may want to read up on ruby methods: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_methods.htm but I think @sawa's answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: whatever the operations on @tmp ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat under-specified, but it looks like you want to do some dynamic attribute assignment.

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :foo

  def initialize
    @foo = "asdf"
  end

  def my_function(var, set_to = "hello")
    self.instance_variable_set(var, set_to)
  end
end
```

usage:

```
t = Test.new # t.foo is "asdf"

t.my_function(:@foo) # t.foo is "hello"

t.my_function(:@foo, "bananas") # t.foo is "bananas"
```

Notably, you have to pass `my_function` a *symbol* representing your variable that you want to dynamically alter, not the variable itself.