# Replacement for PEAR: MDB2 on PHP 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, pear, mdb2

I've been using pear packages in php for years.  I'm in the process of upgrading/moving a sites that uses the MDB2 pear package and it has not been updated for PHP 5.3.X.

In 5.3, MDB2 is returning those new annoying errors.

```
Unknown: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /usr/local/lib/php/MDB2.php on line 390
```

I know I can change my error reporting settings to get rid of them, but I'd rather not make any exceptions.  Anyway,  Is anyone else using MDB2 these days and have a solution?  Are there similar database packages you recommend?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would definitly go for an ORM, at least if you are working on a big project, for which you don't want to use `mysqli_*` or PDO functions/methods directly -- [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) being the most developped/used, nowadays *(It's the default ORM of the symfony Framework, and can be integrated in Zend Framework quite easily)*.

About the `E_DEPRECATED` errors, though : PHP 5.3 is quite young, and lots of libraries/software/projects have not been adapted yet -- you'll probably have lots of those in the next couple of months :-(

Comment: Yeah I agree about the immaturity of PHP 5.3, and I understand that it's going to take some time for us all to update our code, but I don't think MDB2 will ever be updated (looks abandoned to me).

Doctrine look great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can also upgrade to the beta 3 version via the command line

```
pear upgrade MDB2-beta
pear upgrade MDB2_Driver_Mysql-beta
```

Explanation of why current stable version isn't compliant with strict error reporting:
http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=9756

Source for the command:
http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=18050

Comment: Just throwing this out there - I updated to MDB2-beta using the commands above and my site started breaking without throwing errors. Still trying to figure out how to fix it with the client in question currently freaking out about the site being broke.

Comment: Edit: ok it was actually from a Fatal Error bug in Mail/Queue that was recently introduced. I updated my pear packages while I was in there and that's how I introduced the bug. Looks like the patch hasn't made it to the updates yet but it was easy enough to edit the file myself.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to comment on this, since it's coming up high on Google search results for the problem.

I contacted the lead developer for MDB2, who said:

> please check out a copy of MDB2 from SVN, it's fully PHP5.3 compatible, with many performance improvements. I'm currently waiting for some fixes to the new SQL Server driver (Microsoft is working on it this very week), then I'll push a new stable release.

(Edit, 4 years later: This is no longer right, do not do this)

Answer (score 3):

I just went and downloaded the latest version of MDB2 (MDB2-2.5.0b3) from here http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/download and it has got rid of all my errors. Seems to work fine with PHP Version 5.3.5

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html) database support or use an ORM like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I got around all the deprecated errors and warnings, using MDB2 and PHP 5.3, 
but I've gotten some really weird errors on MDB2, so wondering what's up under the hood. 
My environment is CentOS, PHP 5.3, MDB2-2.4.1, MySQL 5.0.77

Anytime, I use autoExecute 2x in a php file, the 2nd is failing (same goes if I try to use prepare and then execute).  I've been logging to my MySQL query log, and while a successful INSERT will show the values, a failed INSERT will always have only the placeholders.  ie:  values(?, ?, ?, ?).  And the MDB2_Error will always mention *RECURSION*

lastInsertID()  never worked with MySQL tables and autoincrement fields (with mysqli driver) 
  I did enough debugging on it, going deep into the call stack, and the result get's so wrapped up in Objects, that you can't tell what it is, until the very end.
I'd love to be using MDB2 more, but in fact, I've had to revert back to straight mysql, numerous times because of these issues.  Maybe Lucas or other developers might shed some light on this subject, or point us in the right direction.

Comment: http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=18050 says you need to upgrade your MDB2 version from 2.4.1 to 2.5.0b3

Answer (score 0):

If you only use MDB2 for MySQL, you can replace it and keep majority of the functions with MDBDid: http://azure-dev.kiao.net/648-mdb2
You will only have little code to adapt.