# PHP Pear missing 'MDB2.php'

Tags: php, ssh, pear, shared-hosting, mdb2

Once this website is moved to another server, I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'MDB2.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php5.4:/usr/lib/php5.4/') in 
>    /homepages/14/xxxxxx/htdocs/public_html/includes/pdbconnection.php on line 3

I've looked up where Pear might be located via PHPInfo() and I got this (`--with-pear=/usr/lib/php5.4`) which is why it's looking there for MDB2.php.

Although it's shared hosting I have SSH access. From what research I've done, it seems that typing `pear install MDB2` should fix everything, but when I do I get the following response:

> WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use
>   "channel-update pear.php.net" to update Cannot install, php_dir for
>   channel "pear.php.net" is not writeable by the current user

Which leads me to believe I'm sunk... Am I? :-(

Thanks for any help!

---

When I type `pear list` I get the following (if that's of any use):

```
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package              Version State
Archive_Tar          1.3.2   stable
Console_Getopt       1.2.1   stable
DB                   1.7.13  stable
HTML_Template_IT     1.1     stable
HTTP                 1.4.0   stable
HTTP_Header          1.2.0   stable
Mail                 1.1.14  stable
Net_SMTP             1.2.10  stable
Net_Socket           1.0.8   stable
Net_UserAgent_Detect 2.0.1   stable
PEAR                 1.5.0   stable
Structures_Graph     1.0.2   stable
XML_Beautifier       1.1     stable
XML_Parser           1.2.8   stable
XML_RPC              1.5.1   stable
XML_Util             1.1.4   stable
```

Thanks!

Comment: Last release of MDB2 was 2012-10-29... may not support PHP 5.4 ? See: http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/redirected

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Thanks, very interesting! I see there were some issues initially with 5.3, too, but they seemed to have been ironed out according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530112/replacement-for-pear-mdb2-on-php-5-3?rq=1. I wonder what the status is for 5.4.

Comment: you probably have to use an alternative library then.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have write permissions to the install directory (/usr/lib/php5.4) when logged in as your standard user. Ordinarily I'd suggest you use sudo to run the same command as root.

So something like this:

```
$ sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net
```

But you're on shared hosting so you could either ask support to do that for you or download the required packages and put them somewhere else inside your include_path.