# PHP Debuggin through eclipse

Tags: php, pear, config

I have a script that starts from root directory(//htdocs) in xampp. The filename of script is y index.php, there is some issue in php file and that is

```
if(file_exists('includes/dboperations.php')). If I run this script, its ok I will get following error 

Call Stack 
# Time Memory Function Location 
1 0.0045 400376 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0 
2 0.0304 455088 require_once( 'C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\library.inc.php' ) ..\index.php:45 


Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80 
Call Stack
```

What does this error indicates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086539/assigning-the-return-value-of-new-by-reference-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

remove the `&` from `C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80`

`return value of new by reference` is deprecated in php 5.3