# MongoClient Class vs. MongoDB\Driver\Manager Class

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to get your recommend about my web project. I use PHP and MongoDB but I was confused when I read this sentence from php documentation.

This extension that defines this class is deprecated. Instead, the MongoDB extension should be used. Alternatives to this class include:
MongoDB\Driver\Manager

I already used MongoClient Class for CRUD but after reading that sentence, I tried to migrate MongoClient to MongoDB\Driver\Manager. The connection using MongoDB\Driver\Manager was successed but I couldn't anymore :(

My PHP version is 5.6.29.
Mongo extension version is 1.7.0
MongoDB extension version is 1.2.9

My questions are:
Do I have to use MongoDB\Driver\Manager Class?
Is it better than MongoClient Class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a good answer about deprecated language features:
[What does PHP do with deprecated functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822446/what-does-php-do-with-deprecated-functions)

And here is a proper usage for php with mongodb:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$filter = [];
$options = [
    'sort' => ['_id' => 1],
];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('db.collection', $query);

foreach ($cursor as $document) {
//...
}
```

There are are a lot of tutorials for CRUD operation with php and mongodb, for example: [MongoDB PHP tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mongodbphp/)

In short: you should not use deprecated feature because of security reasons and because it could get removed from php in the future. So better update your code.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask more? What is MongoDB\Driver\Command Class? I can't understand when it is used.

Comment: "The MongoDB\Driver\Command class is a value object that **represents a database command**." For Example: `$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(['ping' => 1]);` or `$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["count" => "collection", "query" => $query]);`

Comment: With following command you can count documents that contain this string "world":  `$query = ["hello" => "world"];
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["count" => "collection", "query" => $query]);`

Answer (score 1):

I personally came across with the absence of a link to **'vendor/autoload.php'**. It started working after my code looked like the following:

```
  $DB_CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb://YourCredentials";
  require '../vendor/autoload.php';
  $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( $DB_CONNECTION_STRING );
```

Then if you use MongoDB\Driver\Manager, a modern version of MongoDB driver, you implement CRUD operations such as the following:

***Create** a document in the collection*:

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$doc = ['name' => 'John', age => 33, profession => 'Guess what?'];
$bulkWrite->insert($doc);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```

***Read** document in the collection* by name with a limit:

```
$filter = ['name' => 'John'];
$options = ['limit' => 2];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$manager->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

***Read** document in the collection* by MongoDb _id with a limit:

```
$filter = ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( '5bdf54e6d722dc000f0aa6c2' )];
$options = ['limit' => 2];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$manager->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

***Update** document in the collection*:  (Read more about options upsert and multi [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-bulkwrite.update.php))

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter = ['name' => 'John'];
$update = ['$set' => ['name' => 'Smith', age: 35, profession => 'Guess what?']];
$options = ['multi' => false, 'upsert' => false];
$bulkWrite->update($filter, $update, $options);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```

***Delete** document in the collection - Delete*:

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter = ['name' => 'John', age => 35];
$options = ['limit' => 1];
$bulkWrite->delete($filter, $options);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```