# How to get selecting fields from MongoDB aggregate group value in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, distinct, php-5.6

How to get other related column values from MongoDB aggregate group value in PHP?

I can get distinct value by below code in PHP5.6. The database `db_x` with table/collection `table_x`, expecting `$group` columns, there are also some other column is what I need, can I get other columns value?

```
$res = $db_x->command (
        array(
            "aggregate" => "table_x",
            "pipeline" =>
                array(
                    array( '$group' => array( "_id" => ['id' =>'$code_y', 'name' => '$code_x', 'color' => '$color']))
                array( "$replaceRoot" => array( "newRoot" => "$_id" ))
                ),
            "cursor" => ['batchSize' => 200]
        )
);
```

Comment: @Chilarai I would like to get `group by` results, not `distinct` only has one field value

Comment: Which MongoDB PHP package did you use? And also what is `$test->command`? Provide more details in your question

Comment: php5.6 and mongodb 4.0.13

Comment: I meant which PHP-mongodb connection manager ? See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45705786/mongoclient-class-vs-mongodb-driver-manager-class

Comment: 1.6.16, that doesn't matter, I guess

Comment: After the `$group` stage the only fields that exist will be the ones mentioned in the group.  In order to get other fields, include them in the `$group` stage using one of the accumulator operators.

Comment: But I don't need to accumulator any field......

Comment: Only accumulator operations can be used in `$group`.  If you just want to pick one of the values, try `$first` or `$last`

Comment: Got it, thanks so much

Comment: @Joe Hi, nobody answered, I only if ask you for help! I am sorry to bother you again and again, do you know to get all related aggregate values by field name with MongoDB and PHP? 
php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63381352/get-all-related-aggregate-values-by-field-name-with-mongodb-and-php