# How to separate array from nested arrays with MongoDB and PHP aggregate?

Tags: php, mongodb

I would like to get the distinct `code_y` values, and I use below code, the output is equal to `select distinct code_y from table_x`,

```
$res = $db_x->command (
        array(
            "aggregate" => "table_x",
            "pipeline" =>
                array(
                    array( '$group' => array( "_id" => ['id' =>'$code_y', 'name' => '$code_x', 'color' => '$color']))),
            "cursor" => ['batchSize' => 200]
        )
);
```

I got results as below, I don't need `[_id] => Array`, just id, name and color, How to separate array from nested arrays with MongoDB and PHP aggregate? Or how to put `[_id] => Array` together with `id, name and color`? as in my front-end htmls pages, I got `[object] [Object]` because of those nested arrays.

---

```
   [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => Array
                (
                    [id] => a1
                    [name] => bbb
                    [color] => blue
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [_id] => Array
                (
                    [id] => a2
                    [name] => aaa
                    [color] => blue
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [_id] => Array
                (
                    [id] => a3
                    [name] => abc
                    [color] =>red
                )

        )
```

---

What I want is as below:

```
[0] => Array
    (
       [id] => a1
       [name] => bbb
       [color] => blue
    )

[1] => Array
    (
       [id] => a2
       [name] => aaa
       [color] => blue


    )

[2] => Array
    (
      [id] => a3
      [name] => abc
      [color] =>red
    )
```

Comment: Can you add to your aggregate `[$unwind => "$_id"]` i.e `array(''$unwind" => "$_id")`

Comment: you mean change the third line to `"aggregate" => "table_x",['$unwind' => "$_id"],`? it doesn't work,it returns nothing

Comment: No, asking you to add another one after group

Comment: It doesn't work, I add and test it several places, all got nothing.

Comment: Could you please update the query which you tried to the question?

Comment: $unwind doesn't work, no need to update, I guess, you can try it locallay

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: What I want is as below:
```
     [0] => Array
        (
           [id] => a1
           [name] => bbb
           [color] => blue
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
           [id] => a2
           [name] => aaa
           [color] => blue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
          [id] => a3
          [name] => abc
          [color] =>red
        )

Comment: @Joe hey, I already updated my quesiton, thanks for reading my posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a another stage after the group.

You could either use project and list each field:

```
array( '$project' => array( 
     "id" => '$_id.id',
     "name" => '$_id.name',
     "color" => '$_id.color'
))
```

or `$replaceRoot` to grab them all:

```
array( '$replaceRoot' => array( "newRoot" => '$_id' ))
```

Comment: Dear Joe, the second `$replaceRoot` solved my problem!!! You saved my day!!!!!!Thanks so so so much!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Hi Joe, do you know how to get selecting fields from MongoDB aggregate group value in PHP? If you know it, I invite you to answer my other question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351032/how-to-get-selecting-fields-from-mongodb-aggregate-group-value-in-php