# JasperServer with PHP

Tags: php, jasperserver

I tried to run a sample PHP code that comes with JasperServer.  When I load `index.php`, I got the following message:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTTP\Request.php on line 412
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTTP\Request.php on line 736
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTTP\Request.php on line 749
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\pear\HTTP\Request.php on line 794
>
> Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class Net_URL in C:\xampp\php\pear\Net\URL.php on line 124
>
> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\php-sample\index.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\registration\php-sample\index.php on line 13

How can I fix the problem?

I'm using JasperServer 4.7 with PHP 5.4.7 (XAMPP 1.8.1).

Comment: @BogdanBurim, Surely you're joking...

Comment: As you see he didn't provide any code we can fix.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086539/assigning-the-return-value-of-new-by-reference-is-deprecated

Comment: I just tried the code in https://gist.github.com/26205 and http://sneakybits.blogspot.com/2008/11/php-client-for-jasperserver-via-soap.html  It worked.  But I still wonder why the sample code is not working.

Comment: Problem in a PEAR package? Notify its author or file a bug report. You can fix the last two errors yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can change PHP's error_reporting settings to not show deprecated/strict warnings. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
Redefining already defined constructor for class Net_URL in C:\xampp\php\pear\Net\URL.php on line 124
```

Is because the Net_URL PEAR package has a PHP4 compatibility in it that causes the error on more recent versions. The best thing to do is replace Net_URL with something a bit more modern (e.g. NET_URL2) - but if you need a quick fix to get legacy code working just edit the file URL.php (get the location from the error message) and remove or comment out the following block:

```
/**
* PHP4 Constructor
*
* @see __construct()
*/
function Net_URL($url = null, $useBrackets = true)
{
    $this->__construct($url, $useBrackets);
}
```