# Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

Tags: php, variable-assignment, deprecated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086539/assigning-the-return-value-of-new-by-reference-is-deprecated)

I'm trying to correct some mistakes that are displayed in my website, but I can not get rid of them.

For the following code:

```
    $string = preg_replace('# +#', ' ', $string);
    if($useHtml2text){
        $string=new html2text($string);
        $string=$string->get_text();
    }
    return trim($string);
}
```

I have this mistake

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /htdocs/modules/googleshopping/class/myTools.php on line 56

the line concerned is this one

```
$string=new html2text($string);
```

I've tried almost everything but it is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errant code isn't in your script, but in `/htdocs/modules/googleshopping/class/myTools.php` on line 56.

A bit of time in Google suggests that this is a Prestashop module of some sort?  Take it up with the module author.  Tell them to get their act in gear, new-by-ref has been bad practice since PHP *5.0*.  Considering that the top Google result is also complaining about deprecated errors (about `ereg` -- ewwwww), I wish you luck.  You might want to find an alternate module...

In the mean time, if you're seeing this *on a production site*, you'll want to turn off deprecated notices by adjusting `error_reporting` wherever most appropriate for your code, either in your init / bootstrap file or in php.ini.

Comment: thanks a lot, I actually bought this module to a french guy that do "no support". Actualy I have many trouble with that module In fact he told me that this module is compatible with pretashop 1.5 but I have too many mistakes. I'm trying to get rid of them step by step.

thank you for the advices I appreciate that

Comment: If you paid for that code, get your money back as the author is blatantly incompetent.

Comment: I've paid 79 € for that. he do not want, I've signaled to the moderator but actualy I have no responses. I almost get rid of all errors. I have a last one.

Comment: Beware! Deprecated warnings often turn into fatal errors in subsequent releases!

Comment: that is what I get, actually I removed all deprecated but I have that when I try to generated the xml for export on the line 420 `$product_link = $link->getProductLink((int)($product['details']->id), $product['details']->link_rewrite, $cat_link_rew, $product['details']->ean13, $lang['id_lang']);`

This mistakes goes on Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductLink() on a non-object in /htdocs/modules/googleshopping/googleshopping.php on line 420

I'm trying to see what can be the cause of that mistake

Comment: Did you "get rid" of the deprecated error by, say, removing the line of code that was throwing it?  The line of code causing the error is the creation of a new object.  If that object later becomes the `$link` defined (or, rather, *not* defined) in the error you've just given here, that explains that.

Comment: in fact there was that caracter "&" so I removed them all where it was suggested then I have no mistakes like that, just this fatal error at the end

Comment: Okay.  You'll want to consider a new question for that issue.  If you can't track it down on your own, and do decide to post a new question, you'll want to be sure to include the entire function body inside of the question, which will be needed.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciated your patience