# Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in phpExcelReader\Excel\reader.php on line 261

Tags: php, warnings, deprecated

Anybody having any idea, why it says:

`Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in phpExcelReader\Excel\reader.php on line 261`

`$this->_ole =& new OLERead();`

I am using `WAMP - PHP Version 5.3.13`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086539/assigning-the-return-value-of-new-by-reference-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be some old php syntax or method, I changed my code and it worked for me:

Earlier:

`$this->_ole =& new OLERead();`

Change to: (removed & ampersand)

`$this->_ole = new OLERead();`

The warning and notices are gone now !

Comment: Yes. Check here too http://icfun.blogspot.in/2009/09/php-how-to-read-xls-file.html#Blog1_cmt-7645961569389698711

Answer (score 1):

According to advice here http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/issues/detail?id=82

> problem is in 
>    $this->_ole =& new OLERead();
>   sorry for obviousness, but it can be fixed with, for example, this
>    $t = new OLERead();
>    $this->_ole =& $t;

I changed `$this->_ole = new OLERead();` to

```
    $t = new OLERead();
    $this->_ole =& $t;
```

No error message and data also imported. So all works. But not sure if the change will not cause some other problems. If someone knows, please, advice.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one. this works perfectly.**

excel_reader2.php :

turn off : //function OLERead(){ }

and change :

```
/**
* Constructor
*
* Some basic initialisation
function Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($file='',$store_extended_info=true,$outputEncoding='') {
    $this->_ole = new OLERead();
    $this->setUTFEncoder('iconv');
    if ($outputEncoding != '') { 
        $this->setOutputEncoding($outputEncoding);
    }
    for ($i=1; $i<245; $i++) {
        $name = strtolower(( (($i-1)/26>=1)?chr(($i-1)/26+64):'') . chr(($i-1)%26+65));
        $this->colnames[$name] = $i;
        $this->colindexes[$i] = $name;
    }
    $this->store_extended_info = $store_extended_info;
    if ($file!="") {
        $this->read($file);
    }
} */
```