# Updated server from php 5.6 to 7.3, getting PEAR error

Tags: php, centos, pear, centos6

I recently updated my server php version from 5.6 to 7.3.  When I attempt to load a page I'm seeing the following parse error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in
> /usr/share/pear/MDB2/Driver/mysqli.php on line 940

The file above is automatically installed via pear, here is the section prompting the error:

```
938 
939         $class_name = 'MDB2_Statement_'.$this->phptype;
940         $obj =& new $class_name($this, $statement, $positions, $query, $types, $result_types, $is_manip, $limit, $        offset);
941         $this->debug($query, __FUNCTION__, array('is_manip' => $is_manip, 'when' => 'post', 'result' => $obj));
942         return $obj;
943     }
944
```

I've updated all pear packages using pear upgrade-all, restarted httpd and continue to get the same error above.

Comment: Do share the relevant code snippet with us...

Comment: added snipped from PEAR's provided mysqli.php file

Comment: change `=&` to `=`

Comment: Try and get rid of the `&` in `$obj =& new ...`. Objects shouldn't, and don't need to, be created by reference.

Comment: did a find/replace on all =&, that resolved the problem.  If you'll make this an answer I'll approve and upvote you. Would appreciate an upvote here since I've updated the question text as requested.

Comment: For reference, this older thread explores through the `=& new` issue: [Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086539/assigning-the-return-value-of-new-by-reference-is-deprecated)

Comment: I hope the question remains up since I wouldn't have known to look for the referenced question verbatim.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the `=&`, which should be simply `=`, in `$obj =& new ...`. Objects can't, shouldn't, and don't need to, be created by reference. Such an expression was deprecated in PHP 5 and made invalid in PHP 7 (see [`eval`](https://3v4l.org/1TiUd) response on different PHP versions).

It's a mystery to me why the PEAR package should have this, it must be a vestige from forever ago. It makes no more sense than `$x =& [];` (which would also result in an error). When an object is assigned to a variable, the variable becomes a pointer to the object. Therefore:

```
$a = new stdClass();
var_dump($a);
// object(stdClass)#1 (0) {}

$b = $a;
var_dump($b);
// object(stdClass)#1 (0) {}

var_dump($a === $b);
// bool(true)
```

That is: even without assigning `$b =& $a`, both variables point to the same object by default (ie. to `object(stdClass)#1`). Clean those up and drop a note to the PEAR package maintainers. FYI, the [MDB2_Driver_mysqli](https://pear.php.net/package/MDB2_Driver_mysqli) package was last updated on 2012-10-23, so fetching the latest updates won't help much. Look for an up-to-date replacement. (Core PHP has had `mysqli` built in since PHP 5 and also has [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) if you need code portability between different RDBMs).

Comment: It looks like your package wasn't updated after all; the latest (beta) release (from 2012) updates the package to be PHP 5.3 compatible. Looking at the [source code](https://pear.php.net/package/MDB2_Driver_mysqli/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_MDB2__MDB2_Driver_mysqli-1.5.0b4MDB2Drivermysqli.php.html), the "offending" line would be 1173, and there is no more `&=` there. Regardless, this package hasn't been updated for 9 years presumably because it has become largely obsolete with superseding developments in PHP core.

Comment: This legacy app was written about 12 years ago, so yeah - lots of code to rewrite.

Comment: ahh so basically I cannot use PEAR with php7.3... sad!

Comment: Well you can use PEAR but not the MDB2 package that is basically abandoned. Really there's a lot of stuff in PEAR extensions that are poorly maintained. I personally don't trust anything PEAR to stay up to speed. Any dependency your application has on a given package there, be prepared to either be locked down to an old PHP version or fork and maintain a version for your needs. I haven't ever found a good reason to couple PEAR stuff into what I develop.