# PHP object arguments behaviour

Tags: php, object, reference, arguments

Take this situation:

```
function edit($var)
{
    $var->test = "foo";
}

$obj = new stdClass;
edit($obj);

echo $obj->test; //"foo"
```

The edit function does not take the argument as a reference and it should not modify the original object so why does this happen?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107016/are-objects-in-php-passed-by-value-or-reference

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP can someone explain cloning vs pointer reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611986/in-php-can-someone-explain-cloning-vs-pointer-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in PHP 5, references to objects are passed by value, as opposed to the objects themselves. That means your function argument `$var` and your calling-scope variable `$obj` are distinct references to the same object. [This manual entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) may help you.

To obtain a (shallow) copy of your object, use [`clone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php). In order to retrieve this copy, though, you need to return it:

```
function edit($var)
{
    $clone = clone $var;
    $clone->test = "foo";
    return $clone;
}

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj2 = edit($obj);

echo $obj2->test;
```

Or assign it to a [reference argument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), then call it like so:

```
function edit($var, &$clone)
{
    $clone = clone $var;
    $clone->test = "foo";
}

$obj = new stdClass;
edit($obj, $obj2);

echo $obj2->test;
```

Comment: So there's no way in that function to modify only a copy of the object?

Comment: If you clone, you should add a return statement to get the object you did modify

Answer (score 1):

Classes attributes in php (as well as other languages like javascript) are always passed as references

Comment: Variable References != Object References.  They are different concepts with different effects.  Don't confuse them...