# Stop PHP Object behaving like reference

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an object array but in loop it behaves like PHP reference.

Also I create an array in the same struct and it worked as it should.

I want to add a key named as "processed" in sub items, In object array struct, all the sub items are updating, but I want to update just specific items, as in the array-based example. Please see the example to further understand what I mean.

[Click here to run this code in PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/u7ih-zxbn)

```
            // OBJECT
            $pool = [
                    1 => (Object)[
                        'id' => '1',
                        'title' => 'Pool 1'
                    ],
                    2 => (Object)[
                        'id' => '2',
                        'title' => 'Pool 2'
                    ],
                ];

            $items = [
                (Object)['id' => 1],
                (Object)['id' => 2],
            ];

            $vars = [];
            foreach ($items as $i => $item) {

                $vars[$i] = $item;
                $vars[$i]->pool = $pool;

                $vars[$i]->pool[$item->id]->processed = true;
            }


            // ARRAY
            $pool1 = [
                    1 => [
                        'id' => '1',
                        'title' => 'Pool 1'
                    ],
                    2 => [
                        'id' => '2',
                        'title' => 'Pool 2'
                    ],
                ];

            $items1 = [
                ['id' => 1],
                ['id' => 2],
            ];

            $vars1 = [];
            foreach ($items1 as $i1 => $item1) {

                $vars1[$i1] = $item1;
                $vars1[$i1]['pool'] = $pool1;

                $vars1[$i1]['pool'][$item1['id']]['processed'] = true;
            }


            ?>

            <h4>
                Object result
            </h4>
            <pre
                <?php print_r($vars); ?>
            ></pre>


            <h4>
                Array result
            </h4>
            <pre
                <?php print_r($vars1); ?>
            ></pre>
```

Result is

```
            Object result
             stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [pool] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1
                                        [title] => Pool 1
                                        [processed] => 1
                                    )

                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2
                                        [title] => Pool 2
                                        [processed] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [pool] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1
                                        [title] => Pool 1
                                        [processed] => 1
                                    )

                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2
                                        [title] => Pool 2
                                        [processed] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
            >
            Array result
             Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [pool] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1
                                        [title] => Pool 1
                                        [processed] => 1
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2
                                        [title] => Pool 2
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [pool] => Array
                            (
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1
                                        [title] => Pool 1
                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2
                                        [title] => Pool 2
                                        [processed] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
            >
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are objects in PHP passed by value or reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107016/are-objects-in-php-passed-by-value-or-reference)

Comment: Yes, objects in PHP are passed by reference. What's your question?

Comment: I supposed it was like an array but my mistake. The cloning solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *clone* each of the objects inside `$pool`, otherwise a reference to the same set of objects is held in every copy of `$pool` that you create. It's not the array which is "behaving like a reference", it's the objects within it, which are behaving as they're supposed to.

Doing this will result the behaviour you want:

```
$vars = [];
foreach ($items as $i => $item) {

    $vars[$i] = $item;
    $vars[$i]->pool = $pool;

    //clone each of the objects
    foreach($vars[$i]->pool as $key => $obj) {
      $vars[$i]->pool[$key] = clone $obj;
    }

    $vars[$i]->pool[$item->id]->processed = true;
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php for more info on cloning.

Comment: I did clone main array but it was not enough to solve. Now i also clone sub items as you said and solved my issue. This is very intersing and hard to see. Thank you very much!

Comment: @empax No problem. Cloning an array would have no meaningful effect as they are not held by reference in the same way. In fact, if you did that I'm surprised you didn't get an error saying that you can't clone a non-object?

Comment: sorry my mistake, it is an object in main array. Yes you are right, the array cloning gives exception "__clone method called on non-object" :) 
Thanks again.