# Get second to last value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm frequently using the following to get the second to last value in an array:

```
$z=array_pop(array_slice($array,-2,1));
```

Am I missing a php function to do that in one go or is that the best I have?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
end($array);
$z = prev($array);
```

This is more efficient than your solution because it relies on the array's internal pointer. Your solution does an uncessary copy of the array.

Comment: I like this, better than my answer. :)

Comment: But for example, if you pass (without ampersand) the array to a function, as your code modifies the internal cursor of the array, it would trigger a copy of the whole array, whereas the "array_slice" method doesn't touch the internal cursor, thus doesn't trigger a copy, and is actually more efficient. Refs [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-copied-as-value-or-as-reference-to-new-variables-and-when-pas) for further reading.

Comment: A side effect of using this: it will change to array's internal pointer, if you use the `current()` function afterwards it also give the second last item.

Answer (score 17):

For numerically indexed, consecutive arrays, try `$z = $array[count($array)-2];`

Edit: For a more generic option, look at Artefecto's answer.

Comment: Only works if the array is indexed numerically, it starts with 0 and there are no gaps.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret I choose your answer better because yours just 1 line & 1 function, so I can directly do `<?=$array[count($array)-2]?>`

Answer (score 7):

Or here, should work.

```
$reverse = array_reverse( $array );
$z = $reverse[1];
```

I'm using this, if i need it :)

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a very old question, I'll add a couple more solutions:

#### OP's method:

The OP's method is actually fine but the use of `array_pop()` is both unneeded and also throws the notice "*Only variables should be passed by reference*." With that in mind, it's perfectly fine to just do:

```
$z = array_slice($array, -2, 1);
```

#### Methods that require numerically indexed array:

While the other two methods require the array to be numerically indexed, they still work with the addition of `array_values()` which uses very little overhead.  I benchmarked these and found not much difference at all with this method:

```
// index method
$z = array_values($array)[count($array) - 2];

// reverse method
$reverse = array_reverse($array);
$z = array_values($reverse)[1];
```

Finally, I ran some benchmarks using all the above answers and from my tests, the answer by @Artefacto using `end()` and `prev()` was *by far the fastest - coming in roughly 2x to 3x faster than all the others.