# Use string to store statement (or part of a statement), and then add it to the code

Tags: php

I use multidimensional arrays to store product attributes (well Virtuemart does, to be precise).
When I tried to echo the sub-arrays value, if the sub-array did not exist PHP threw:

> Fatal error: Cannot use string offset
>   as an array

To get around this, I attempted to create a function to check on every array level if it is an actual array, and if it is empty (when trying on the whole thing at once such as: `is_array($array['level1']['level2']['level3'])`, I got the same error if `level1` or `level2` are not actual arrays).

This is the function (`$array` contains the array to check, `$array_levels` is an array containing the names of the sub-arrays, in the order they should apper):

```
function check_md_array($array,$array_levels){
    if(is_array($array)){
        $dimension = null;  //This will store the dimensions string

        foreach($array_levels as $level){
            $dimension .= "['" . $level . "']"; //Add the current dimension to the dimensions string

            if(!is_array($array/* THE CONTENT OF $dimension SHOULD BE INSERTED HERE*/)){
                return false;
            }
        }           
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can I take the string contained in $dimensions, and insert it into the code, to be part of the statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short of doing an `eval`, I don't think you can do it.

```
if(eval("!is_array($array".$dimension.")"))
    return false
```

However, this is another way to do it

```
function check_md_array($array,$array_levels){
    if(!is_array($array))
         return false;

    foreach($array_levels as $level){
        if(!isset($array[$level]) || !is_array($array[$level]))
            return false;
        $array = $array[$level];
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Better use a reference instead of copying the array.

Comment: @Dean: You need to use a separate variable for the reference and not `$array` itself.

Comment: @Gumbo: I see. If I am using a reference to the same array, that means if I'm iterating over it, I am modifying the array pointer. Or I misunderstood you, please explain it a bit more.

Comment: @Damp: Sincerest apologies, I made a mistake. It works perfectly fine. +1 and answer accepted.

Comment: @dean Thx! Also, regarding the pointer, that's exactly right.

Comment: @Dean: You would just use the reference to walk though the array. But as it’s only a reference, you’re not changing/copying parts of the array as it’s only the reference that changes. So instead of `$array` you would use a reference on `$array` like `$ref = &$array` and then use that reference `$ref` instead of the original `$array` (i.e. `$ref = &$ref[$level]`, etc.).

Comment: @Gumbo: First, if the function catches the passed array into a variable it is creates a copy of the original array. Any modifications that are maid to the array in the function (iterating modifies the pointer) affect the copy only. If I use a reference, that means the reference is actually pointing to the same place in memory that holds the original array, any modification to the reference will modify the original array. In my case I want to perform a test on the array WITHOUT MODIFYING it.

Comment: @Gumbo: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-passed-by-value-or-by-reference

Comment: @Dean: Using a reference on the array doesn’t alter it in any way. But as the parameter is passed by value and `foreach` works on an internal copy of the array, it doesn’t matter whether you’re using just a reference to walk the array or copying the parts over and over as you it doesn’t change the original array anyway.

Comment: From php.net:"Unless the array is referenced, foreach operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself. foreach has some side effects on the array pointer. Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the foreach without resetting it. "

Comment: @Dean: That array pointer refers to the internal array pointer that PHP maintains for every array. But this only affects `current`, `key` and other functions that change that internal array pointer: `$arr = array(0,1,2); end($arr); var_dump(key($arr)); // int(2) foreach ($arr as $val) {} var_dump(key($arr)); // NULL and not int(2)`