# Returning array inside function that returns another value

Tags: php

Why does the following script does not work?

```
$arr = array();

function collect( $array , $val) {
    $array[] = $val;
    return $array;
}

function checkFoo( $s ) {

    $valid = true;

    if ( strlen( $s ) === 0 ) {
        $isValid = false;
        collectFoo( $arr , $s );
    }

    return $valid;
}

function checkBar( $t ) {

    $valid = true;

    if ( strlen( $s ) != 10 ) {
        $isValid = false;
        collectFoo( $arr , $t );
    }

    return $valid;
}

if ( checkFoo( $that ) && checkBar( $this ) ) {

    echo "success"; 

} else {

    print_r( $error );

}
```

I always get

```
Notice: Undefined variable: error in /my.php on line 12
```

where line 12 resembles the second occurrence of `collect(...)`;

I know that a function can only return one value, but what if a function returns something in a function that returns something? Because `collect` returns `$array` inside `checkBar` that returns `$valid`.

Comment: what is `$this` and `$that` and `$error` and `collectFoo` function ?

Comment: `$this` & `$that` are placeholders. `$error` is an array that is just still there from debugging, `collectFoo` is a function that adds something to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a global variable ($arr), so you need do declare it as such. example:

```
function checkFoo( $s ) {
    global $arr; // declare $arr to be usable inside this function scope
    $valid = true;

    if ( strlen( $s ) === 0 ) {
        $isValid = false;
        collectFoo( $arr , $s );
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

You need more practice, because totally your code is incorrect !
you must changes this parts of your codes :

```
$arr = array();

function collectFoo( $arr , $val) {
    global $arr;

    $arr[] = $val;
}

function checkFoo( $s ) {
    global $arr;

    $valid = false;
    if ( strlen( $s ) === 0 ) {
        $valid = false;
        collectFoo( $arr , $s );
    }
    return $valid;
}

function checkBar( $t ) {
    global $arr;

    $valid = true;
    if ( strlen( $t ) != 10 ) {
        $valid = false;
        collectFoo( $arr , $t );
    }
    return $valid;
}

$a = checkFoo( $that );
$b = checkBar( $this );
if ( $a && $b ) {
    echo 'Success !';
} else {
    print_r( $err );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I only get `Array ( [0] => [1] => )`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't declaring your `$arr` variable as global inside the functions that use it.  You can find some info about that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Also, it doesn't look like you are actually using the return value of `collect`, so I'd say that your problem is that either `checkBar` or `checkFoo` are returning false, which makes you fall through to the `print_r` function, with a `$error` variable that you have not initialized.

Finally, it seems to me like your `collect` function is not actually doing anything to the `$arr` variable, because you are not passing it to `collect` by reference.  you can read up on passing variables by reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). There is also a S.O. question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-passed-by-value-or-by-reference).