# Why are PHP references a bad idea? How do zvals and Copy On Write come into it?

Tags: php, reference, copy-on-write

I've recently discovered that using references in PHP is generally (although not always) a bad idea from a memory management or performance point of view, because of Copy On Write and the way that variables are represented under the hood using zvals.

Can someone offer a fuller explanation? I have seen this link posted a few times on Stack Overflow: http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html

I also found this reference, which goes into a bit more detail about zvals and how they work.  It's in French though, although Google does a pretty good job of translating it: http://julien-pauli.developpez.com/tutoriels/php/internals/variables/

I'm surprised there isn't any more, or better documentation on this, and I wondered if any other Stack Overflow users have come across any clearer or more accessible documentation that I haven't been able to find?

Comment: "Don't use references" is the bottom line of the article you linked to. Now what is your question?

Comment: My question is, where can I find good documentation on this?  It seems an important subject for PHP developers, and yet I've only found 2 explanations - one of which is a blog post which only partly explains the reason for the problem and one of which, although it has more detail, is in French.

Why the down vote?

Comment: Everything that is used incorrectly is a bad idea. What is your use case for a referencing variables/parameters?

Comment: zerkms - the articles I referenced explain why using references in PHP is nearly always a bad idea, but not very clearly (the first in less detail and the 2nd in French).  What I'm looking for is some good documentation on this subject.  My question has been changed though, because it seems this was considered "off-topic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sara Golemon has an interesting article at http://blog.golemon.com/2007/01/youre-being-lied-to.html

> The moral of the story
>
> Assigning values by references when you don't need to ... is NOT a
>   case of you outsmarting the silly engine and gaining speed and
>   performance. It's the opposite, it's you TRYING to outsmart the engine
>   and failing, because the engine is already doing a better job than you
>   think.

And some [background on zvals in general](http://devzone.zend.com/317/extension-writing-part-ii-parameters-arrays-and-zvals/). But both these are a bit old. Not sure how much has changed over the years.

Comment: Thanks for this. In terms of answering the question, I think the first article comes closest & is the most accessible, although it puts the focus more on passing objects and also the differences with PHP 4. I see my question has been closed as off topic, and this is the best answer, so I've marked it as correct. It seems a big omission to me that there isn't any clearer and more official documentation on this subject!