# PHP: Return a reference to an array element

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way in PHP to return a reference to an element in array?

```
function ref(&$array, &$ref) { $ref = $array[1]; }
$array = array(00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99);
ref($array, $ref);
$ref = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
var_dump($ref);
var_dump($array);
```

I expect that $array will be changed as in the following code:

```
$array = array(00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99);
$ref = &$array[1];
$ref = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
var_dump($ref);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Or read this quite good SO answer if you are not a friend of manuals http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-passed-by-value-or-by-reference

Comment: See this documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've found two ways to return reference to an array element:

### 1. Using return by reference and =&

```
    function & ref(&$array)
    {
            return $array[1];
    }

    $array = array(00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99);
    $ref =& ref($array);
    $ref = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    var_dump($ref);
    var_dump($array);
```

### 2. Put reference into an array

```
    function ref(&$array, &$ref = array())
    {
            $ref = array();
            $ref[] = &$array[1];
    }

    $array = array(00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99);
    ref($array, $ref);
    $ref[0] = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    var_dump($ref);
    var_dump($array);
```