# When we pass an array as an argument to a function, what actually gets passed?

Tags: php, arrays, function

When we pass an array as an argument to a function, what actually gets passed?

Someone told me that it is "Base address of the array"? but I am not sure about it. How this array is processed then?

Comment: Are you taking a test right now?

Comment: No actually I am not sure about my answer & I need some more elaboration on this topic if any one have.

Comment: Do I get a credit for the course if I tell you the right answer??

Comment: possible duplicate of [are arrays in php passed by value or by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-passed-by-value-or-by-reference)

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes sure how much?

Comment: Too late, @Andrew already got the course credit. I could have helped if it was a multiple choice. I would have said the answer was "c"...that's always the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the answer: [Are arrays in PHP passed by value or by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-passed-by-value-or-by-reference)

Comment: So is it base address or addresses of each array element?

Comment: If you feel an existing answer shows the question to be a duplicate, please flag it rather than creating more duplication.

Comment: I flagged it a while back... Mr. Boss man @halter