# Why are variables shared across scopes in python when using django views

Tags: python, django

Please Note this is a very Django specific question, so if you know the Django Rest Framework you will understand it

So I have a view in Django rest framework with an update function over ridden and a _has_permission helper function

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        permission, message = self._has_permission(data=request.data)
        if not permission:
            return Response({'error': message}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)



    def _has_permission(self, data):
        """
       Resolves if the logged in user has permission to update the data given the type of data
       :param data:
       :return:
       """


        data['user_type'] = data['user_type'] if ('user_type' in data and data['user_type']) else None

        ....
        some checks
        ....
        return True, 'Has Permission'
```

In the case where the function _has_permission()  sees that 'user_type' is not in data, it sets data['user_type']  = None   in the function, but when it comes out request.data['user_type'] now exists and becomes None as well

How is this dictionary being shared across two different scopes. I thought functions have their own scopes

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're explicitly passing the dictionary from `update` to `_has_permission`.

Comment: yes, but is a copy of the dictionary not made?

Comment: No, why should it be? And what would be doing it?

Comment: Maybe i have been coding for too many hours straight, for the past 5 years i was of the belief that if you pass a variable to a function it will now be in a different scope

Comment: dictionary is mutable, so no, not a copy. a shallow copy would be enough here so pass `data.copy()`.

Comment: But this has nothing to do with scope. Why do you think it does?

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing python with PHP? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-passed-by-value-or-by-reference

Comment: So crazy i did not know this, i feel silly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to your assertion, this is *not at all* specific to DRF, but a very general Python principle.

Passing any argument to a function always passes the object itself. If you then mutate that object in the function, all other references to that object will see that modification, because they remain references to the same object.

Comment: i meant specific to DRF because i did not paste the whole class and only specific DRF functions

Answer (score 0):

By default, in Python, all args are passed by reference (or a kind of), which mean, you are passing a reference to the object, not a copy, so if you alter the object inside a function, you are affecting the object itself, not a copy of it. You can see more details at http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/