# Are arrays passed by reference or value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Are arrays passed by reference or value in PHP?

For example, let's see this code.

```
function addWeight($arout, $lineCountry, $lineDomain, $target, $weight)
{
    $currentDomain=getDomain();
    $currentCountry=getCountry();

    if ($currentCountry==$lineCountry && ($currentDomain == $lineDomain || $lineDomain==""))
    {
        $tarobreakpoint=0;
        $arout [$target] =  intval($weight);
    }

    return $arout;
}
```

Basically it took an array as a parameter. Depending on some circumstances it adds elements to the array. I wonder if this is efficient? If `$arout` is passed by reference like all arrays should then I think it's efficient. But if it's just copied and passed by value then well it's not.

So what's the verdict?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-passed-by-value-or-by-reference?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are arrays in PHP passed by value or by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-passed-by-value-or-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), PHP arrays are passed by value:

> Array assignment always involves **value copying**. Use the reference operator to copy an array by reference.

If you'd like to pass an array's reference, use the corresponding operator (&) as mentioned above, and remove the `return $arout;` line in the `addWeight()` function:

```
<?php
// pass $array by reference using & operator
addWeight(&$array, $lineCountry, $lineDomain, $target, $weight);
```