# Set variable in foreach loop and pass by reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

I was playing with PHP recently and wanted to assign variable in foreach loop and pass value by reference at the same time. I was a little bit surprised that didn't work. Code:

```
$arr = array(
    'one' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'two' => 'zzzzzzzz'
);

foreach ($foo = $arr as &$value) {
    $value = 'test';
}

var_dump($foo);
```

Result:

```
array(2) { ["one"]=> string(8) "xxxxxxxx" ["two"]=> string(8) "zzzzzzzz" }
```

The following approach obviously does work:

```
$arr = array(
    'one' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'two' => 'zzzzzzzz'
);

$foo = $arr;

foreach ($foo as &$value) {
    $value = 'test';
}

var_dump($foo);
```

Result:

```
array(2) { ["one"]=> string(4) "test" ["two"]=> &string(4) "test" }
```

Does someone know why those snippets are not equivalent and what is being done behind the scenes?

Comment: [Are arrays in PHP passed by value or by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2030906/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

`$foo = $arr` is trans by value, not reference, you should use `$foo = &$arr`. You can refer to [Are arrays in PHP passed by value or by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2030906/6521116)

try this, [live demo](https://eval.in/818296).

```
$arr = array(
    'one' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'two' => 'zzzzzzzz'
);

foreach ($foo = &$arr as &$value) {
    $value = 'test';
}

var_dump($foo);
```

Comment: Ok, but doing it this way we change the 'arr' array too ;) I don't want to do this. With this approach there is no point to reassign variable to 'foo' - it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($foo = $arr as &$value) {
    $value = 'test';
}
```

first you assign the value of $arr[0] to $foo[0] then take that value and make that value = 'test' (this will not change $arr or $foo values "useless statement")

But here

```
$foo = $arr;
foreach ($foo as &$value) {
    $value = 'test';
}
```

first you asign $arr to $foo
then go to for each statement , get the values of  $foo and modify it 
ex: $foo[0]='test' , $foo[1]='test' ...

Comment: why it won't change $arr or $foo values if &$value is passed by reference?