# When is foreach with a parameter by reference dangerous?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, pass-by-reference

I knew, that it can be dangerous to pass the items by reference in foreach.

In particular, one must not reuse the variable that was passed by reference, because it affects the `$array`, like in this example:

```
$array = ['test'];
foreach ($array as &$item){
    $item = $item;
}
$item = 'modified';
var_dump($array);
```

> array(1) {
>     [0]=>
>     &string(8) "modified"
>   }

Now this here bite me: the content of the array gets modified inside the function `should_not_modify`, even though I don't pass the `$array` by value.

```
function should_not_modify($array){
    foreach($array as &$item){
        $item = 'modified';
    }
}
$array = ['test'];
foreach ($array as &$item){
    $item = (string)$item;
}
should_not_modify($array);
var_dump($array);
```

> array(1) {
>     [0]=>
>     &string(8) "modified"
>   }

I'm tempted to go through my whole codebase and insert `unset($item);` after each `foreach($array => &$item)`.

But, since this is a big task and introduces a potentially useless line, I would like to know if there is a simple rule to know when `foreach($array => &$item)` is safe without a `unset($item);` after it, and when not.

**Edit for clarification**

I think I understand what happens and why. I also know what is best to do against: `foreach($array as &$item){...};unset($item);`

I know that this is dangerous after `foreach($array as &$item)`:

- reuse the variable `$item`
- pass the array to a function

My question is: Are there other cases that are dangerous, and can we build an exhaustive list of what is dangerous. Or the other way round: is it possible to describe when it is not dangerous.

Comment: "Dangerous" is subjective. Sometimes it's useful or necessary.

Comment: @tadman Yes, like a knife: It is often useful and necessary, but it is dangerous.

Comment: @poke You are wrong, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-passed-by-value-or-by-reference, arrays are passed by value. In my case, the array is passed by value, but the `$item` inside remains a reference after `foreach`.

Comment: Array passed by value. look there - https://eval.in/932720 Your prolbem is with assignment $item  -  when $item is reference, you save not value, but reference. pay attention to & in var_dump

Comment: It's dangerous when you modify the array structure in the foreach, It can do "spooky things"

Comment: Ok, now I'm really confused. This isn't how I thought PHP worked at all, and it's not actually anything to do with looping by reference. It's an issue with *any* reference to the array existing outside of the function: see https://eval.in/932728

Comment: @LorenzMeyer *In my case, the array is passed by value, but the $item inside remains a reference after foreach* it not so - change ibn function item to any other name

Comment: @LorenzMeyer If your programming language has no sharp edges it's probably useless. A butter knife might be safe, but good luck cutting down a tree with it. PHP doesn't really have a good way of communicating the intent of a function like C++ does with explicit references. You'll need to convey the intent in either the name of the function, a comment, or some kind of variable naming convention.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer https://eval.in/932753 - this line `$item =& $array[0];` makes $array[0] as reference!!! I don't understand that !!!

Comment: @splash58 Isn't this what the operator `=&` is supposed to do ?

Comment: I think, that i don't right.  `In the first of these, PHP references allow you to make two variables refer to the same content. Meaning, when you do:
$a =& $b;  it means that $a and $b point to the same content.` - from there http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php. So, both variables are set as reference. But I never thought about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### About foreach

First of all, some (maybe obvious) clarifications about two behaviors of PHP:

1. `foreach($array as $item)` will leave the variable `$item` untouched after the loop. If the variable is a reference, as in `foreach($array as &$item)`, it will "point" to the last element of the array even after the loop.
2. When a variable is a reference then the assignation, e.g. `$item = 'foo';` will change whatever the reference is pointing to, *not* the variable (`$item`) itself. **This is also true for a subsequent `foreach($array2 as $item)`** which will treat `$item` as a reference if it has been created as such and therefore will modify whatever the reference is pointing to (the last element of the array used in the previous `foreach` in this case).

Obviously this is very error prone and that is why you should always `unset` the reference used in a `foreach` to ensure following writes do not modify the last element (as in [example #10](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) of the doc for the type array).

### About the function that modifies the array

It's worth noting that - as pointed out in a comment by @iainn - the behavior in your example has nothing to do with `foreach`. The mere existence of a reference to an element of the array will allow this element to be modified. Example:

```
function should_not_modify($array){
    $array[0] = 'modified';
    $array[1] = 'modified2';
}
$array = ['test', 'test2'];
$item = & $array[0];

should_not_modify($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Will output:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(8) "modified"
  [1] =>
  string(5) "test2"
}
```

This is admittedly very suprising but [explained in the PHP documentation "What References Do"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

> Note, however, that references inside arrays are potentially dangerous. Doing a normal (not by reference) assignment with a reference on the right side does not turn the left side into a reference, but references inside arrays are preserved in these normal assignments. **This also applies to function calls where the array is passed by value.** [...] In other words, the reference behavior of arrays is defined in an element-by-element basis; the reference behavior of individual elements is dissociated from the reference status of the array container.

With the following example (copy/pasted):

```
/* Assignment of array variables */
$arr = array(1);
$a =& $arr[0]; //$a and $arr[0] are in the same reference set
$arr2 = $arr; //not an assignment-by-reference!
$arr2[0]++;
/* $a == 2, $arr == array(2) */
/* The contents of $arr are changed even though it's not a reference! */
```

It's important to understand that when creating a reference, for example `$a = &$b` then both `$a` and `$b` are equal. `$a` is not pointing to `$b` or vice versa. `$a` and `$b` are pointing to the same place.

So when you do `$item = & $array[0];` you actually make `$array[0]` pointing to the same place as `$item`. Since `$item` is a global variable, and references inside array are preserved, then modifying `$array[0]` from anywhere (even from within the function) modifies it globally.

### Conclusion

> Are there other cases that are dangerous, and can we build an exhaustive list of what is dangerous. Or the other way round: is it possible to describe when it is not dangerous.

I'm going to repeat the quote from the PHP doc again: "references inside arrays are potentially dangerous".

So no, it's not possible to describe when it is not dangerous, because it is never *not* dangerous. It's too easy to forget that `$item` has been created as a reference (or that a global reference as been created and not destroyed), and reuse it elsewhere in your code and corrupt the array. This has long been a topic of debate (in [this bug for example](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29992)), and people call it either a bug or a feature...

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is the best, but I'd like to give a complement: When is `unset($item);` not necessary after a `foreach($array as &$item)` ?

- `$item`: if it is never reused after, it cannot harm.
- `$array`: the last element is a reference. This always dangerous, for all the reasons already stated.

So what does change that element form being a reference to a value ?

- the most cited: `unlink($item);`
- when `$item` falls out of scope when the array is returned from a function, then the array becomes 'normal' after being return from the function.

  ```
  function test(){
      $array = [1];
      foreach($array as &$item){
          $item = $item;
      }
      var_dump($array);
      return $array;
  }
  $a = test();
  var_dump($a);
  ```

  > array(1) {
  >     [0]=>
  >     &int(1)
  >   }
  >   array(1) {
  >     [0]=>
  >     int(1)
  >   }

  **But beware:** if you do anything else before returning, it can bite !

Answer (score -2):

You can break the reference by "json decode/encode"

```
function should_not_modify($array){
    $array = json_decode(json_encode($array),false);
    foreach($array as &$item){
        $item = 'modified';
    }
}
$array = ['test'];
foreach ($array as &$item){
    $item = (string)$item;
}
should_not_modify($array);
var_dump($array);
```

The question is purely academic, and this is a bit of a hack.  But, it's sort of fun, in a stupid programming way.

And of course it outputs:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>string(4) "test"
}
```

As a side the same thing works in JavaScript, which also can give you some wonky-ness from references.

I wish I had a good example, because I've had some "weird" stuff happen, I mean like some quantum entanglement stuff. This one time at a PHP camp, I had a recursive function ( pass by reference ) with a foreach ( pass by reference ) and well it sort of ripped a hole in the space time continuum.

Comment: Using `unset($item);` after the foreach loop is much better than `json_decode(json_encode())`, both from a performance perspective and for code readability. Also, modifying the function is wrong, because the function should remain generic.

Comment: The question is *why* there is a reference within the function, not how to "break" it.

Comment: @iainn -  I fully understand that.  But thanks for mentioning it.