# PHP: Array referencing other array (unintentional)

Tags: php, arrays

The question was what's gonna be printed when the code below is executed?

My answer was:

```
arr[0]=1 and arr2[0]=2
```

But apparently, no. As seen during execution, the answer appears to be arr[0]=2 and arr2[0]=2. Now, that confuses me - why would `arr[0]` be 2, if it wasn't even referenced, and as such shouldn't be changed when `arr2[0]` was modified?

```
$a = 1;
$arr = array(1);
$a = &$arr[0]; //$a=1
$arr2 = $arr;
$arr2[0]++; //$arr2[0]=2
echo "arr[0]=".$arr[0]. "<br>";
echo "arr2[0]=".$arr2[0]. "<br>";
```

I'm probably missing something embarrassingly obvious, but can't seem to figure it out. Thanks, in advance!

Comment: `what's gonna be printed when the code below is executed?` - Hm? What about executing that code?

Comment: Question is misleading. You are asking what's gonna be printed when you have executed the code yourself and stating the results are different than what you expect.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2030924/4524061) answer

Comment: Fun fact: even though we never actually do something with `$a`, it still messes up what OP expected: https://3v4l.org/hqasB

Comment: Marcin, please read the question again. I did execute it.

Comment: I'm not asking what's gonna be printed. I'm asking why that is printed, instead of the first one being 1 and the second one being 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this assignment `$a = &$arr[0];` you've created reference in $arr. This reference will then be copied to $arr2. If you call `var_dump($arr, $arr2);` you'll see that first element is a reference in both arrays.

This case is perfectly described in [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php#83325) at php.net.

Comment: Huh... This is it, I guess.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$arr = array(1);
$a = $arr[0]; //$a=1
$arr2 = $arr;
$arr2[0]++; //$arr2[0]=2
echo "arr[0]=".$arr[0]. "<br>";
echo "arr2[0]=".$arr2[0]. "<br>";
```

remove the & from `$a = &$arr[0];` and you will get your expected result

Read more about ampersand in php [Here!!!](https://www.phpreferencebook.com/samples/php-pass-by-reference/)

Comment: I get that. I did that, as well. But the code in the assignment is with that part.