# PHP: Passing array by reference fail

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I've the following code function:

```
function foo(&$vett) {

    $vettore = $vett;

    $vettore[] = "ciao";

    var_dump($vettore);
}

$v = array();

foo($v);

var_dump($v);
```

When I dump the final array is empty. Have you any idea of what could be?

Comment: What is passed by reference here?

Comment: Now I fixed the question

Comment: So if you pass something by reference - __what's the point__ of assigning passed value to another one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-passed-by-value-or-by-reference may be useful

Comment: When you fixed it, you can post your own answer and accept it. Beside the reputation, your solution may be of some help for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$v` never modified. Inside the function you assign the variable into another variable. So nothing ever happen to the old `$vett`

try something like:

```
function foo(&$vett) {
    $vett[] = "ciao";
    echo __LINE__;
    var_dump($vett);
}

$v = array();
foo($v);
var_dump($v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct version is:

```
function foo(&$vett) {
    $vett[] = "ciao";
}

$v = array();
foo($v);
var_dump($v);
```