# Laravel Update Controller Variable

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

Is there a way to update controller variable value from view

MainController.php

```
$pageData['count'] = 0;
$data = array('data' => $pageData);
return view('home', $data);
```

In my home view i included another view

```
<!-- Block 1-->
@include('home.prodbox', $prodData = $data['data'])

<!-- Block 2-->
@include('home.prodbox', $prodData = $data['data'])
```

In the first block foreach loop count starts with 0. Depends of data, loop runs multiple times and count will increase. So i want to pass the count of first block to second block Like if first block loop count is 4 then i want second block count to start from 5. So in prodbox i did it like this:

prodbox.blade.php

```
$tabcount = $data['count'];
```

And at the end of prodbox.blade.php file, I did this

```
$data['count'] = $tabcount;
```

But when second block runs it starts with 0 again. I set the data variable to latest count but why it always zero. Is there a way i update data from view to controller.

Comment: May be because you/your code initialize variable again. You should try reference &$data['count']

Comment: Like this ? &$data['count']  = $tabcount;

Comment: yes and in second block get data again from reference. http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-passed-by-value-or-by-reference

Comment: &$data gives syntax error in laravel view

Comment: and <!-- Block 2-->
@include('home.prodbox', $prodData = &$data['data'])

Comment: So i have to pass throw include statement. Currently its in file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184739/discussion-between-digital-jedi-and-daremachine).