# Convert JavaScript function to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JS function, with array inputs.
For example:

> x=[ 239709880, 250229420, 109667654, 196414465, 13098 ]
> y=[ 78135241, 54642792, 249 ]

OR:

> x=[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
> y=[ 78135241, 54642792, 249 ]

OR:

> x=[ 49 ]
> y=[ 33 ]

```js
function bdiv(x,y) {
    var n=x.length-1, t=y.length-1, nmt=n-t, arr = []
    if(n < t || n==t && (x[n]<y[n] || n>0 && x[n]==y[n] && x[n-1]<y[n-1])) {
        arr['q']=[0]
        arr['mod']=x
        return arr
    }
    if(n==t && toppart(x,t,2)/toppart(y,t,2) <4) {
        var q=0, xx
        for(;;) {
            xx=bsub(x,y)
            if(xx.length==0) break
            x=xx; q++
        }
        arr['q']=[q]
        arr['mod']=x
        return arr
    }
    var shift, shift2
    shift2=Math.floor(Math.log(y[t])/log2)+1
    shift=bs-shift2

    if(shift) {
        x=x.concat()
        y=y.concat()
        for(i=t; i>0; i--) y[i]=((y[i]<<shift) & bm) | (y[i-1] >> shift2); y[0]=(y[0]<<shift) & bm
        if(x[n] & ((bm <<shift2) & bm)) { x[++n]=0; nmt++; }
        for(i=n; i>0; i--) x[i]=((x[i]<<shift) & bm) | (x[i-1] >> shift2); x[0]=(x[0]<<shift) & bm
    }
    var i, j, x2, y2,q=zeros(nmt+1)

    y2=zeros(nmt).concat(y)

    for(;;) {
        x2=bsub(x,y2)
        if(x2.length==0) break
        q[nmt]++
        x=x2
    }
    var yt=y[t], top=toppart(y,t,2)
    for(i=n; i>t; i--) {
        m=i-t-1
        if(i >= x.length)
            q[m]=1
        else if(x[i] == yt)
            q[m]=bm
        else
            q[m]=Math.floor(toppart(x,i,2)/yt)
        topx=toppart(x,i,3)
        while(q[m] * top > topx)
            q[m]--
        y2=y2.slice(1)
        x2=bsub(x,bmul([q[m]],y2))
        if(x2.length==0) {
            q[m]--
            x2=bsub(x,bmul([q[m]],y2))
        }
        x=x2
    }
    if(shift){
        for(i=0; i<x.length-1; i++)
            x[i]=(x[i]>>shift) | ((x[i+1] << shift2) & bm);
        x[x.length-1]>>=shift
    }
    while(q.length > 1 && q[q.length-1]==0)
        q=q.slice(0,q.length-1)
    while(x.length > 1 && x[x.length-1]==0)
        x=x.slice(0,x.length-1)
    arr['q']=q
    arr['mod']=x
    return arr;
}
```

What I have done under 5 days so far in PHP:

```php
function bdiv($x,$y){
    global $bs, $bm, $bx2, $bx, $bd, $bdm, $log2;
    $arr=[];
    $n=count($x)-1;
    $t=count($y)-1;
    $nmt=$n-$t;

    if($n < $t || $n==$t && ($x[$n]<$y[$n] || $n>0 && $x[$n]==$y[$n] && $x[$n-1]<$y[$n-1]))
        return ['q'=>[0], 'mod'=>$x];

    if($n==$t && toppart($x,$t,2)/toppart($y,$t,2) <4){
        $q=0;
        for(;;){
            $xx=bsub($x,$y);
            if(count($xx)==0)
                break;
            $x=$xx;
            $q++;
        }
        return ['q'=>[$q], 'mod'=>$x];
    }

    $shift2=floor(log($y[$t])/$log2)+1;
    $shift=$bs-$shift2;
    if($shift){

/////////////////////////////////////////////// Booboo
        //$x = array_merge(array(),$x);
        //$y = array_merge(array(),$y);

        for($i=$t; $i>0; $i--)
            $y[$i]=(($y[$i] << $shift) & $bm) | ($y[$i-1] >> $shift2);
        $y[0]=($y[0] << $shift) & $bm;
        if($x[$n] & (($bm << $shift2) & $bm)){
            $x[++$n]=0;
            $nmt++;
        }
        for($i=$n; $i > 0; $i--)
            $x[$i]=(($x[$i] << $shift) & $bm) | ($x[$i-1] >> $shift2);
        $x[0]=($x[0] << $shift) & $bm;
    }
    $q=zeros($nmt+1);

    //array_push($arr, zeros($nmt));
    //array_push($arr, $y);
    //$y2=array_merge(...$arr);
    //////////////////////////////////// use array_merge straight away
    $y2=array_merge(zeros($nmt),$y);

    for(;;){
        $x2=bsub($x,$y2);
        if(count($x2)==0)
            break;
        $q[$nmt]++;
        $x=$x2;
    }

    $yt=$y[$t];
    $top=toppart($y,$t,2);

    for($i=$n; $i>$t; $i--){
        $m=$i-$t-1;
        if($i >= count($x))
            $q[$m]=1;
        else if($x[$i] == $yt)
            $q[$m]=$bm;
        else
            $q[$m]=floor(toppart($x,$i,2)/$yt);

        $topx=toppart($x,$i,3);
        while($q[$m] * $top > $topx)
            $q[$m]--;

        $y2=array_slice($y2,1);
        $x2=bsub($x,bmul([$q[$m]],$y2));

        if(count($x2)==0){
            $q[$m]--;
            $x2=bsub($x,bmul([$q[$m]],$y2));
        }
        $x=$x2;
    }

    if($shift){
        for($i=0; $i<count($x)-1; $i++)
            $x[$i]=($x[$i] >> $shift) | (($x[$i+1] << $shift2) & $bm);
        $x[count($x)-1] >>= $shift;
    }

    while(count($q) > 1 && $q[count($q)-1]==0)
        $q=array_slice($q, 0, count($q)-1);
    while(count($x) > 1 && $x[count($x)-1]==0)
        $x=array_slice($x, 0, count($x)-1);

    return ['q'=>$q, 'mod'=>$x];
}
```

So as I marked in the PHP code I have a problem with the **array_push($x,$x)**, seems like this is not the equivalent of **x=x.concat()**.
Array_push add the whole current $x values as a new element to the existing **$x** array:

> $x=[ 1, 2, 3 ];
> array_push($x,$x);
> then $x will be [ 1, 2, 3, [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]

If I try to flatten the array (**$x=array_merge(...$x);**) then a new PHP error shows up: *array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array*

I would really appreciate it if anyone have any idea, how to convert properly this JS function to a PHP version.
Thanks in advance.

> ==========================> UPDATE I

@Kiran Shakya idea to replace x=x.concat() with $x=array_merge(array(),$x); is actually working or at least I don't get any PHP error or warning on that, but start an infinite loop, which I have to shut manually. The script calling the toppart function, which operating with arbitrary precision numbers (multiply and add):

```js
    function toppart(x,start,len) {
        var n=0
        while(start >= 0 && len > 0){
            n=n*bx2+x[start--]
            len--
        }
        return n
    }
```

The interesting part is, the JS returned for an example 70144566321522750 but the PHP returned 70144566321522751. In the later loop the differences are much bigger.
I have checked all numbers in both versions and all the same inputs: x,start,len,bx2. This can be a bug or one of them cannot handle big integers or what can be the reason?

> ==========================> UPDATE II

I applied Booboo solution, I just completely skipped the concat() parts

So the inputs are:

> $x=[ 210763776, 109357119, 261308872];
> $start=2;
> $len=2;
> $bx2=268435456;

...and returns 70144566321522751 in PHP and 70144566321522750 in JS. I use bcadd() and bcmul() but the result is same if I'm using math operator signs.

```php
function toppart($x,$start,$len){
    global $bs, $bm, $bx2, $bx, $bd, $bdm, $log2;
    $n=0;
    while($start >= 0 && $len > 0){
        $n= bcadd(bcmul($n, $bx2),$x[$start--]);
        $len--;
    }

    return $n;
}
```

Comment: Googling the code, it looks like it's [an arbitrary-precision division function](https://downloads.tuxfamily.org/se3xref/nav.html?se3master/var/www/se3/crypto.js.source.html#l122). If that's the case, why don't you just use [bcmath's `bcdiv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)?

Comment: @AKX Exactly this is my version! Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this function and as I read a bit, the inputs are strings, not arrays.

Comment: `x=x.concat()` in js means to clone a new array from x and return it to x. The reason to do it is not mutate the original input. In php, you may use `array_slice($x, 0)` to return a new array from it instead of `array_push($x,$x);`

Comment: your javascript function isn't runnable, on line 21 it references a `bs` variable which doesn't exist. what is bs supposed to be on line 21's `shift=bs-shift2` ?

Comment: also references a function that doesn't exist, what is the function `zeros` supposed to do?

Comment: @hanshenrik This is a little part of the whole file. bs=28 (global value) and the zeros function is creating an array with zeros. nmt = 3; q=zeros(nmt+1); creating this => q=[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]

Answer (score 4):

If what you are doing with `x = x.concat()` is attempting to ensure that the original passed array is not being modified by your function, **you do not have to do anything to ensure that in your PHP version of this function because by default arguments will be copied rather than passed by reference**. To force an array to be passed by reference in PHP, you must preceded the argument name with an ampersand (`&`). This can be demonstrated with the following program where we have defined two functions that each modify the first element of the passed array. In the first function, `test1`, the array argument is copied so the original passed array remains unmodified. But in the second function, `test2`, the array argument is passed by reference and when the function returns, the original passed array will have been modified. The only difference between the two functions is that in `test1` the arguments is defined as *$x* and in `test2` as *&$x*:

```php
<?php

// $x is passed by value:
function test1($x)
{
    $x[0] = 9;
    print_r($x);
}

// $x is passed by reference:
function test2(&$x)
{
    $x[0] = 9;
    print_r($x);
}

$my_array = [0, 1, 2];
echo "Pass by value:\n";
test1($my_array); //$my_array remains unmodified
print_r($my_array);

echo "\n\nPass by reference:\n";
test2($my_array); //$my_array is modified
print_r($my_array);
```

Prints:

```
Pass by value:
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)


Pass by reference:
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

**Update**

You have several issues. First, you describe `toppart` returning different values in the JavaScript and PHP versions and you ask us to explain the discrepeancy but you never specify what the actual `start`, `len` and `bx2` value inputs were to the functions and leave us to figure that out for ourselves. And did you post the PHP version of `toppart` because I don't see it.

Second, let me elaborate on my previous response. I should have said that *arrays* will by default be copied rather than passed by reference (class objects *will* be passed by reference, but that is not applicable here). But that is not just for passing arguments to functions. Consider the following:

```php
$a = [0, 1, 2];
$b = $a; // copy-on-write
$b[0] = 9; // $b is [9, 1, 2]
echo $a; // $a is still [0, 1, 2]
```

So if you have a JavaScript array `a` and the assignment `b = a`, which is a reference copy such that if you modify `b` you are modifying the array referenced by `b` you are also modifying the array referenced by `a`, the semantic equivalent in PHP is `$b = @$a;`. This ensures that `$b` and `$a` not only refer to the same array but if you modify the array referenced by `$b`, you will be modifying the same array referenced by `$a`.

So if you have a JavaScript function defined as follows:

```JavaScript
function bdiv(x, y)
{
etc.
```

where $x and $y are arrays, theoretically `bdiv` could modify the actual arrays being passed and aliased as `x` and `y` and therefore the semantic equivalent in PHP would be to define this function as follows:

```PHP
function bdiv(@$x, @$y)
{
etc.
```

But here is the problem. Later on in the JavaScript code we have:

```JavaScript
x=x.concat()
```

In JavaScript you have no choice but to pass array arguments by reference. Ealrly on in the JavaScript code there is:

```
        for(;;) {
            xx=bsub(x,y)
            if(xx.length==0) break
            x=xx; q++
        }
```

The assignment to `x` is conditionally executed but would certainly modify the passed *x* argument. So later on when the code `x=x.concat()` is executed to assign a copy of the current value of `x` to `x`, this would certainly prevent further subsequent modification of the passed array, but what else does it accomplish? *Prior* to the copy of `x` there are assignments such as `arr['mod'] = x` and *after* the copy of `x` is made we have assignments to `x[0]`. Without the copy of `x` being made that assignment to `x[0]` would also be updating the array stored at `arr['mod']`. So the array copy is being done to prevent that.

There are several PHP idioms for making a copy of an array, as already pointed out, for example, `$x = array_merge([], $x)`. But even if you execute this statement in PHP, once you have defined the argument to `bdiv` as *@$x*, i.e. pass by reference, **you would still be subsequently modifying the passed array** as you make assignments to the array referenced by `x`. So there can be no exact PHP equivalent of the JavaScript result as far as what the passed JavaScript `x` array will end being when the function returns. The following PHP program demonstrated that even after a copy of `x` is assigned to `x` and then an assignment is made to the new array referenced by `x`, it updates the passed array:

```PHP
<?php

function test(&$x)
{
    $x = array_merge(array(), $x);
    $x[0] = 9;
    print_r($x);
}

$arr = [0, 1, 2];
test($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Prints:

```None
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

So this array copying will not have the other effect of preventing further modifications to the passed array. As far as I can tell the original JavaScript program actually leaves the original passed array in an undefined state. You might as well leave the PHP function defined as `bdiv($x, $y)` so that the original arrays are left unmodified.

But the above discussion suggests that you may have a problem elsewhere. Where you have a JavaScript assignment of the form `a = b` where `b` is an array and there is a subsequent modification to `a`, for example `a[i] = some_value`, the equivalent PHP code must be `$a = @$b; etc,`, that is, a reference assignment.

And as mentioned in a comment by @AKX, you should look into the BC Math functions if you are having issues with `toppart`.

Comment: To be clearer, array in php is passed by reference but it will copy the array when there is a mutation of the array. There is an answer about this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9740541/14032355

Comment: @ikhvjs Thanks - that's an interesting point! So it's actually a copy-on-write situation. But It is also for all intents and purposes a (possibly release-dependent) implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you think in PHP I can skip that JS part? No needed $x=array_merge(array(),$x); If I remove it, the script behaves differently. I updated the question on the top.

Comment: I have re-evaluated the code and updated the answer. My original answer, which was short-sighted, only addressed the issue of modifying the original passed array. But looking at the program logic, I see the need for making this copy. But there is more in my long-winded update, so please read carefully.

Answer (score 3):

I am confused why your JavaScript code even has:

```
x=x.concat()
y=y.concat()
```

They don't serve any purpose other than assigning a new copy of same array to itself. If it was intended to avoid modification on the original array, then you can simply replace those two lines of code with:

```
$x = array_merge(array(), $x);
$y = array_merge(array(), $y);
```

They both serve exact same purpose.

At this point, I am not sure about rest of the php code that you wrote so far, but if it helps you in anyway, that is fine.

Comment: So far, this is the most working solution: $x = array_merge(array(), $x); The array_merge($x, $x) creating wrong array for $x.

Answer (score 1):

replace array_push with array_merge.

This will return the merged array then store the result in $x;

array_merge is meant for arrays. it will take the values from one array and append it to the other. just like concat does in JS.

... splits the array ($x) into several values, this is not the correct input. it is the equivalent of array_merge(1,2,3) (i.e arrays are not being inputted)

```
$x = array(1,2,3);
$x = array_merge($x,$x);
var_dump($x); //output: [1,2,3,1,2,3]

echo $x[4]; // output: 2
```

if i've misunderstood the question please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Looks like the array_merge is better than array_push, but the first input must be an empty array, not $x itself => $x=array_merge(array(),$x); Now the script just start an infinite loop. I updated the question on the top.

Answer (score 1):

Use array_merge instead of array_push i.e

```
  $x = array(1, 2, 3);
       print_r(array_merge($x,$x));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Looks like the array_merge is better than array_push, but the first input must be an empty array, not $x itself => $x=array_merge(array(),$x); Now the script just start an infinite loop. I updated the question on the top.