# Remove previous iteration's data from re-used array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two arrays, `$array1` and `$array2`. `$array2` is an array of arrays. For each subarray of `$array2`, I want to print `$array1` but with additional entries that depend on whether the `$array2` subarray has keys `"a"` or `"c"` with value `1`. My code prints `$array1` each loop, but there are additional entries in `$array1` for the later iterations that I wasn't expecting. Why do I get these entries, and how do I prevent them?

Sample code:

```
$array1 = array(
    "service" => "coding",
    "data" => array(
        "ITEM" => array(
            array(
                "CODE" => "9999", //STANDARD
                "QUANTITY" => 1
            ),
        )
    )
);

$array2 = array(
    array(
        "a" => "1",
        "b" => "1",
        "c" => "1",
        "d" => "1",
    ),
    array(
        "cancel" => "1",
        "a" => "1",
        "b" => "",
        "c" => "",
        "d" => "1",
    ),
    array(
        "cancel" => "1",
        "a" => "",
        "b" => "1",
        "c" => "1",
        "d" => "",
    ),
);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array2); $i++) {
    foreach ($array2[$i] as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'a' && $value == 1){
            array_push($array1['data']['ITEM'],
                array('SOMETHING' =>  'this_is_a',
                    'ELSE' => "1"
                )
            );
        }
        if($key == 'c' && $value == 1){
            array_push($array1['data']['ITEM'],
                array('SOMETHING' =>  'this_is_c',
                    'ELSE' => "1"
                )
            );
        }
    }

    echo "Loop #$i result:\n";    
    var_export($array1);
    echo "\n";
}
```

You can test the above code as a [PHP Sandbox snippet](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/fdf91).

The actual result is:

> ```
> Loop #0 result:
> array (
>   'service' => 'coding',
>   'data' => 
>   array (
>     'ITEM' => 
>     array (
>       0 => 
>       array (
>         'CODE' => '9999',
>         'QUANTITY' => 1,
>       ),
>       1 => 
>       array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_a',
>         'ELSE' => '1',
>       ),
>       2 => 
>       array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_c',
>         'ELSE' => '1',
>       ),
>     ),
>   ),
> )
> Loop #1 result:
> array (
>   'service' => 'coding',
>   'data' => 
>   array (
>     'ITEM' => 
>     array (
>       0 => 
>       array (
>         'CODE' => '9999',
>         'QUANTITY' => 1,
>       ),
>       1 => 
>       array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_a',
>         'ELSE' => '1',
>       ),
>       2 => 
>       array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_c',
>         'ELSE' => '1',
>       ),
>       3 => 
>       array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_a',
>         'ELSE' => '1',
>       ),
>     ),
>   ),
> )
> Loop #2 result:
> array (
>   'service' => 'coding',
>   'data' => 
>   array (
>     'ITEM' => 
>     array (
>       0 => 
>       array (
>         'CODE' => '9999',
>         'QUANTITY' => 1,
>       ),
>       1 => 
>       array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_a',
>         'ELSE' => '1',
>       ),
>       2 => 
>       array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_c',
>         'ELSE' => '1',
>       ),
>       3 => 
>       array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_a',
>         'ELSE' => '1',
>       ),
>       4 => 
>       array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_c',
>         'ELSE' => '1',
>       ),
>     ),
>   ),
> )
> ```

The loop #0 result is correct, but the later loops have additional entries in `$array1['data']['ITEM']`. Desired result:

> ```
> Loop #0 result:
> array (
>   'service' => coding
>   'data' => array (
>     'ITEM' => array (
>       0 => array (
>         'CODE' => 9999
>         'QUANTITY' => 1
>       )
>       1 => array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_a'
>         'ELSE' => 1
>       )
>       2 => array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_c'
>         'ELSE' => 1
>       )
>     )
>   )
> )
> Loop #1 result:
> array (
>   'service' => coding
>   'data' => array (
>     'ITEM' => array (
>       0 => array (
>         'CODE' => 9999
>         'QUANTITY' => 1
>       )
>       1 => array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_a'
>         'ELSE' => 1
>       )
>     )
>   )
> )
> Loop #2 result:
> array (
>   'service' => coding
>   'data' => array (
>     'ITEM' => array (
>       0 => array (
>         'CODE' => 9999
>         'QUANTITY' => 1
>       )
>       1 => array (
>         'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_c'
>         'ELSE' => 1
>       )
>     )
>   )
> )
> ```

Comment: Please use strong emphasis (`**`) only for text that should be strongly emphasized, not all text in the question. It's very important to ask a question, as opposed to just describing the problem. Also, `var_export` is strongly preferred over `print_r` (and `var_dump`), as the former produces valid PHP code while the latter do not. Study the edited question compared with earlier versions for more examples, and read "[ask]" (and linked articles) for more tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to loop through the second array and only push to the first array's `['data']['ITEM']` when the current iteration has a key named `a` and its value is `1`.

```
$arr1 = [
    'service' => 'coding',
    'data' => [
        'ITEM' => [
            [
                'CODE' => '9999',
                'QUANTITY' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$arr2 = [
    [
        'a' => '1',
        'b' => '1',
        'c' => '1',
        'd' => '1',
    ],
    [
        'cancel' => '1',
        'a' => '1',
        'b' => '',
        'c' => '',
        'd' => '1',
    ],
    [
        'cancel' => '1',
        'a' => '',
        'b' => '1',
        'c' => '1',
        'd' => '',
    ],
];

// loop through the second array ($arr2)
// the "use" is very important here as it let's the callback function to access $arr1 variable
$finalArr = array_map(function ($el) use ($arr1) {
    // if in the current iteration a kley named "a" and its value is "1" is found then push it to the first array's ['data']['ITEM'] key.
    // $arr1 here is passed by value so the real array won't be channged, we're, more or less, working with copy of $arr1 in the function.
    isset($el['a']) && $el['a'] == 1 && ($arr1['data']['ITEM'][] = [
        'something' => 'This is a', // tried to keep same output as yours
        'else' => $el['a'] // tried to keep same output as yours
    ]);
    // for "c" key
    isset($el['c']) && $el['c'] == 1 && ($arr1['data']['ITEM'][] = [
        'something' => 'This is c', // tried to keep same output as yours
        'else' => $el['c'] // tried to keep same output as yours
    ]);
    // return the $arr1 copy regardless of whether we pushed "a" key or not.
    return $arr1;
}, $arr2);

// print the resulting array
print_r($finalArr);
```

Result (for the sample data):

> ```
> array(
>   0 => array(
>     'service' => 'coding',
>     'data' => array(
>       'ITEM' => array(
>         0 => array(
>           'CODE' => '9999',
>           'QUANTITY' => 1,
>         ),
>         1 => array(
>           'something' => 'This is a',
>           'else' => '1',
>         ),
>         2 => array(
>           'something' => 'This is c',
>           'else' => '1',
>         ),
>       ),
>     ),
>   ),
>   1 => array(
>     'service' => 'coding',
>     'data' => array(
>       'ITEM' => array(
>         0 => array(
>           'CODE' => '9999',
>           'QUANTITY' => 1,
>         ),
>         1 => array(
>           'something' => 'This is a',
>           'else' => '1',
>         ),
>       ),
>     ),
>   ),
>   2 => array(
>     'service' => 'coding',
>     'data' => array(
>       'ITEM' => array(
>         0 => array(
>           'CODE' => '9999',
>           'QUANTITY' => 1,
>         ),
>         1 => array(
>           'something' => 'This is c',
>           'else' => '1',
>         ),
>       ),
>     ),
>   ),
> )
> ```

You can learn more about [`callback functions`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (anonymous functions) in the PHP manual.

Comment: Please never use screenshot to present textual data on Stack Overflow -- this prevents users with vision impairment (who use screen reading technology) from being able to "see" your full contribution.

Comment: For reference: "[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527)"

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning `$array1['data']['ITEM']` to its original state between each iteration.  Just write the following between your `for()` and your `foreach()`.

```
$array1['data']['ITEM'] = array_slice($array1['data']['ITEM'], 0, 1);
```

Because array keys must be unique, you don't need to loop through all elements to see if `a` or `c` exists -- this will cost unnecessary cycles.

Futhermore, I find array destructuring to be a good choice to isolate the only two values you seek.

I might recommend this much simpler and more intuitive snippet: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4QNcv))

```
foreach ($array2 as $i => ['a' => $a, 'c' => $c]) {
    $temp = $array1;
    if($a == 1) {
        $temp['data']['ITEM'][] = [
            'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_a',
            'ELSE' => '1'
        ];
    }
    if ($c == 1) {
        $temp['data']['ITEM'][] = [
            'SOMETHING' => 'this_is_c',
            'ELSE' => '1'
        ];
    }

    echo "Loop #$i result:\n";    
    var_export($temp);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The unexpected entries are present because `$array1` is modified with each iteration (specifically, by `array_push`). To prevent this, each iteration must operate on a different copy of `$array1`. Since [variable assignment and argument passing will each copy an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2030906/90527), either could be used. Similar to argument passing, [closures](https://www.php.net/functions.anonymous) can inherit (note: not in the OOP sense) variables from outer scopes, binding to their values (which will copy an array), providing a third potential basis for a solution.

The fix requiring the least amount of edits is to assign `$array1` to another variable at the start of the loop, and replace `$array1` in the rest of the loop with this variable:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array2); $i++) {
    $result = $array1;
    // ...
```

Alternatively, by moving the body of the loop to a function, `$array1` becomes a copy within the function body:

```
function process(array $options, array $output) {
    // Ensure entries to test are present:
    $options += ['a' => NULL, 'c' => NULL];
    /* As an alternative to the above, if entries should be added 
     * to $output whenever 'a' or 'c' has a truthy value, 
     * `! empty(...)` could be used instead of the `... == 1`
     * tests below.
     */

    if ($options['a'] == 1) {
        $output['data']['ITEM'][] = [
            'SOMETHING' =>  'this_is_a',
            'ELSE' => 1,
        ];
    }
    if ($options['c'] == 1) {
        $output['data']['ITEM'][] = [
            'SOMETHING' =>  'this_is_c',
            'ELSE' => 1,
        ];
    }
    return $output;
}

foreach ($array2 as $i => $subarray) {
    echo "// Loop #$i result:";
    var_export( process($subarray, $array1) );
    echo ";\n";
}
```

As a third approach, you could apply [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map) to `$array2`, as is done by [ths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71811478/90527). For comparison, the preceding `foreach` loop could be replaced with a call to `array_map`:

```
var_export(
    array_map(function (array $subarray) use ($array1) {
            return process($subarray, $array1); 
        }, $array2)
);
```

Or, with an [arrow function](https://www.php.net/functions.arrow) (which automatically use variables from the outer scope):

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn (array $subarray) => process($subarray, $array1),
        $array2
)   );
```

Note that for arrays that won't be modified (or for which modification won't matter), you can [pass them by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference) (or bind by reference in closures) to avoid the overhead of copying them.

```
function process(array &$options, array $output) {
    // ...
```