# Appending a string with a php function

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a function which appends a string to an existing string for error handling.

The output that I'm searching:

```
// Begin:
// message1
// message2
```

Currently I have:

```
$error = "Begin:";

function addError($message) {
    $error .= "<br>" . $message;
}

addError("message1");
addError("message2");

echo $error;

// ----- Which outputs -----
// Begin:
```

I would assume that the code above does the same as:

```
$error = "Begin:";

$error .= "<br>" . "message1";
$error .= "<br>" . "message2";

echo $error;

// ----- Which outputs -----
// Begin:
// message1
// message2
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Could someone elaborate on the mistake(s) I'm making?

Comment: The `$error` variable inside the function is not the `$error` variable you used outside. Take a look at [Variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addError($message) {
    $error .= "<br>" . $message;
}
```

The `error` variable only exist in the [function's scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

You could pass the `error` variable as a reference to the function, described with the `&` sign.

```
$error = "Begin:";

function addError(&$error, $message) {
    $error .= "<br>" . $message;
}

addError($error, "message1");
addError($error, "message2");

echo $error;
```

[Test online!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0cf2fc0c24221fcd2404a7bb66e764099c5f4852)

---

On other option would be [defining and changing a global variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127788/changing-a-global-variable-from-inside-a-function-php)