# what are the difference between these operators = and =&

Tags: php, operators

From [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

I found this but confused totally what are the difference between these operators `(= and =&)`

```
$instance = new SimpleClass();

$assigned   =  $instance;
$reference  =& $instance;
```

Can anyone explain about this properly, please?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php

Comment: you could also check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879/php-variables-passed-by-value-or-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may understood as following:

```
$instance = "5";
$assigned = $instance; // stores "5"
$reference =& $instance; // Point to the object $instance stores "5"
$instance = null; // $instance and $reference become null
```

Which means

> $instance has the value "5" would be null
>
> $assigned has the value "5" wouldn't be null coz it is stored with "5"
>
> $reference has the value "5" would be null as it is pointed to $instance

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $a = 1;
    $b = $a;
    $b = 2;
    echo "a:{$a} / b: {$b}<br />";
    // returns 1/2

    $a = 1;
    $b =& $a;
    $b = 2;
    echo "a:{$a} / b: {$b}<br />";
    // returns 2/2
     ?>
Above example clarifies the difference
```