# $array variable isn't equal to $GLOBALS['players'][$name] when defined as $GLOBALS['players'][$name] = array()

Tags: php

Using the code below it doesn't work but when I use

```
<?php
    $GLOBALS['players'] = array();

    function add($name) {
        $array = $GLOBALS['players'][$name] = array();
        array_push($array, "b");
    }

    add("a");
    print_r($players);
?>
```

(outputs: Array ( [a] => Array ( ) )) the code here

```
<?php
    $GLOBALS['players'] = array();

    function add($name) {
        $array = $GLOBALS['players'][$name] = array();
        array_push($GLOBALS['players'][$name], "b");
    }

    add("a");
    print_r($players);
?>
```

(outputs: Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => b ) )) it works fine. Why does $array not work when it is referencing the same array.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/879/3933332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple, when you pass the values to `$array` you're passing the `$GLOBAL` array to a new variable, you're not referencing the variable `$GLOBAL` variable.

In a few words: `$array` and `$GLOBAL` are two differents variables. Doing this is like doing:

```
$a = 10;
$b = $a;
$b++;
print_r($a); // Will not print 11, but 10, because you edited the var $b, that is different from $a.
```

**To solve this little trouble** you must pass the variable to `$array` by referencing it like here:

```
function add($name) {
    $GLOBALS['players'][$name] = array();
    $array = &$GLOBALS['players'][$name];
    array_push($array, "b");
}
```

Comment: Would you mind telling me what prefixing a $GLOBAL with & does?

Comment: Prefixing a variable with & pass the reference of the variable and not the value, so if you edit the variable where you passed the reference, you edit the referenced variable. Look here please: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c3cb0dd2197f4aa03885f4c37bd04ce755d80eb