# php - passing argument to function

Tags: php

I have the simple code:

```
class A {
    public $var = 1;
    function inc() {$this->var++;}
}

function foo($a) {
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $a->inc();
    }
}

$a = new A();
foo($a);

$v = $a->var;
echo "var value is $v \n";
```

I was expecting to get printed the value of 1 but I get 11.
shouldn't PHP pass argument to functions with copy-constructor?

Comment: Why will you get  1 as you have called the loop to iterate 10 times

Comment: I think what he's trying to get at is that `$a` is being manipulated within the local scope of the function and that `$v` is accessing `$a->var` in the global scope.. and as such should have the initial value of `1` rather than `11` ... the short answer is, *it doesn't work like that* but I think I can see where he's coming from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are PHP Variables passed by value or by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879/are-php-variables-passed-by-value-or-by-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does have a copy constructor but it copies shallowly so the object passed to foo is a new copy but it has a reference to $var that points to the same value as $a->var.
If you would have done
foo(clone($a))
then you would have gotten the answer you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You already have `$var=1` and you are incrementing every 10 times. That means that your for loop runs 10 times and it gets incremented as you have `$this->var++` in `class A inc method`. So To get your result your `$var` should be equal to -9 or else you should set the for loop to run single time and set the value of `$var` as 0 by default.