# PHP uses references in for-loop

Tags: php, date

I am looping through a for-loop to fill an array with dates. With each iteration I want to increase the date variable by one day.

```
$myDate = date_create(date_default_timezone_get());
$myArr;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++) {
    $myArr[$i] = $myDate;
    $myDate->modify('+1 day');
}
```

What it returns to me if the current date is 06-November-2021:

```
echo date_format($myArr[0], 'd.m.Y'); //08.11.2021
echo date_format($myArr[1], 'd.m.Y'); //08.11.2021
```

I would expect that it returns **06.11.2021** and **07.11.2021** but it seems it uses some kind of references instead of values in my array. Can someone explain?

Comment: In PHP, as in many other languages, objects are passed by reference. So you're adding and modifying the same object instance. Please check the [clone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) operator.

Comment: "seems it uses some kind of references" -- use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-id to find out yourself.

Comment: I am not really used to PHP programming but I found this thread and thought this would count in general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879/are-php-variables-passed-by-value-or-by-reference

Comment: If you don't need the date object anymore, you should format the date inside your loop and assign the formated string to your array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create a new date and assign it to array try this

```
<?php
$myDate = date_create(date_default_timezone_get());
$myArr;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $myArr[$i] = date_create(date_format($myDate,'d.m.Y'));
    $myDate->modify('+1 day');
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArr);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

result

[image]